# How to make report page default for different customers using Power BI API?

Tags: c#-4.0, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

We are embedding all our customers reports from power bi web to our own website and from there customers can view their insights/reports. Now, customers are requesting for default report page. so instead of viewing main page of report, they want to see their own report page as default. We have many customers, so we have to be done this for all of our customers. **FYI**: we are using c# for writing web services.

What are the ways of doing this? I believe we have to store report bookmarks guid in our database? if so then how can I access that bookmark guid?

so basically, do I need to create a table and store the customer id and bookmark guid for report page and whenever they access I should have to return that page guid according to customer id?

So is there anything to do from power bi API side or just need to make a changes from portal side?
Please suggest any possible ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only about the page, then you can simply store the page name and switch to it programmatically by calling page's [`setActive`](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Page-Navigation) method, or to set the page name to `pageName` property of the [embed configuration details](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details#options) when embedding the report.

If you still want to apply bookmarks, then again you can apply it [on load](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Bookmarks#apply-bookmark-on-load), or [apply predefined state](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Bookmarks#apply-captured-bookmark-state).